# Windows , disabling USB device while hot-plug (no GPO)

Tags: windows, usb

I try to disable a USB device when it is inserted under windows version Family (no GPO). I worked around several languages ​​to reach my end, but without success.I look for a corresponding method to linux udev.

I want to disable the USB device while the 'hot-plug' but I do not know if this is possible.

My first approaches:

> - Setupapi library in C ++ and C #
> - PowerShell cmdlet Disable-PNPDevice
> - The device I want is to disable a keyboard so I also looked around win32_keyboard classes CIM_keyboard and others ...
> - Next step is Windows Drivers ...

My problem with these solutions is that the device should be removed and reinsert for the deactivation takes effect when I want disabling to take effect immediately upon insertion.

In the Windows registry (`HKLM \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ kbdclass or kbdhid`) value named `Start` can be managed (`0x04` = Disable) depending on the class, but if I understand it, if I do this associated service will not start at all, so in these cases that make my second keyboard (main) remains active and I do not find myself without a keyboard.

What do you think of the library libusb-win32?
Is there a specific windows registry key to change the status of the device instantly?

I wanted to know if this is possible and may be guided? Thank you.

Comment: thank, but in my question title it's specified : (no GPO)

Comment: Windows Family don't have GPO ....

Comment: @yagmoth555 Thank's but it's a keyboard not a storage device

Comment: oh, keyboard... will remove my other comment. no, only thing I found is the Start 4 on usbstor like you told, but it will block your other keyboard too.

Comment: No problem, yes I have not tried because it seems logical and I did not find myself without a keyboard.